# JSGrid + JQuery UI Autocomplete custom drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsgrid

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Background:**

I'm trying to create a custom drop-down menu for JQuery UI Autocomplete field, in JSGrid (http://js-grid.com/)

Code: https://codepen.io/MrC0mm0n/pen/poeJPEm

Cross-reference: https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/1393

**Attempted:**

Using example - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Using the autocomplete render item `.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem` creates a cell that's not editable

**Expected result:**

- When user enters '1' in the tag field, drop-down menu with options should show, based on the tags variable
- On selecting an option from the drop-down menu, fields 1, 2, 3 in the row should populate with data